# Count strictly overlapping substrings

Tags: code-golf, string, counting, subsequence

Given two strings `a` and `b`, count how many times `b` occurs as a substring in `a`, but only when it overlaps with another instance of `b`.

(This means that `1` will never be a valid output, because in order for the substring to be strictly overlapping, there must be at least one other instance for it to overlap with.)

### Test cases

```
input a              input b     output

trololololol         trol        0
trololololol         ol          0
trololololol         lol         4
trololololol         LOL         0
HAAAAHAAAAA          A           0
HAAAAHAAAAA          AA          7
Teeheeee             ee          3
123123123123123123   12312312    4
(empty string)       whatever    0
```

`b` will never be an empty string.

### Rules

- Matching must be case-sensitive
- You may use [any sensible IO format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) apply
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20688)

Comment: ... Can we assume that `b` is empty?

Comment: @user202729 clarified (assuming you meant "can we assume that `b` is**n't** empty")

Comment: Suggest a test case where `a` begins with a single occurrence of `b` and later contains overlapped `b`s. [eeheeee](https://tio.run/##tVJNb8MgDL3zK1imVpBSKeluY3TqbYdIOyS3NgdCyRKpg4myD6lK/3rndGu7ZK20ywyyeTZgnrEaPym1210vdVkbjVO89g4mkaygyDHLy3bJFFWVdKFkYcFCxTeldcQJKyIuh8OUKyGZFLVZ6g@SjmLYRZkbCzlWUwG3rbQhBR1eWWpFKoS8h9jWsug25i4Ubhrz5viCDMcROoAETyKEauPxs6wNoXiDEAZpH4PlPMvnSY4FePG3bALv7Oowgob9W@RhBrJXsz8GMq0rDdL1nnXGk5ve7MaDZg8avjenkhQXS9I938e/2CWPSdfR49LlRoBFQC/jE6HuLe@V9PpNuzN02gZr/90Dl4iDucMZmNGI/qB2XLw42FuSYLDGWzxYL8xguTALEzBoEp8zqEuroZWPiNKvZM0ppdP@1RnIhprdJw)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

Expects `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>g=(b,i=(t=0)-.1,p)=>~i?g(b,a.indexOf(b,i+1),i,q=b[i-p]?t-=~!q:0):t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldA7C4MwEADgvb/CZkqo8VELBSGKWwfBpVvp4CPaFDE@QunkX7c@qlKHopcQ7o77CMnTf/lVWLJc4IxHtIlJ4xMrITCQGYGCaAgrupwjYtXMTtqur7Asom8v7iYOOpKZXJDgxnB@twUm9b4wNWSKJuRZxVOqpDyBMQSi5Om4gNQHGrp9hZCkqpK2W6XmfIuaikGd1inXc8G/uy5OG/3hfFGn5nyTcn7edV6qK6UP2sZIBjXVgzKWSj8aiw3Q3AXf32g@)

#### How?

Given the last position **i** of **b** in **a**, we use `a.indexOf(b, i + 1)` to get the position of the next occurrence. We keep track of the previous position in **p** and figure out whether they overlap by testing if `b[i - p]` is defined.

At the very beginning of the process, we initialize **i** to **-0.1** so that it's neither **-1** (that would stop the recursion) nor **0** that would mean that there's a match at position **0**, while still being interpreted as **0** by `.indexOf()`.

Exemple for `a = "XABABA"` and `b = "ABA"`:

```
 iteration |         1 |        2 |    3 |   4
-----------+-----------+----------+------+-----
         i |      -0.1 |        1 |    3 |  -1
         p | undefined |     -0.1 |    1 |   3
     i - p |       NaN |      1.1 |    2 | n/a
     match |  "XABABA" | "XABABA" | none | n/a
                ^            ^
```

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // outer function taking the haystack a
g = (               // inner recursive function g taking:
  b,                //   b = needle
  i = (t = 0) - .1, //   i = pointer in a, initialized to -0.1
                    //   t = output, initialized to 0
  p                 //   p = position of the previous occurrence
) =>                //
  ~i ?              // if i is not equal to -1:
    g(              //   do a recursive call:
      b,            //     pass b unchanged
      a.indexOf(    //     set i = position of the next occurrence
        b,          //       of b in a
        i + 1       //       starting at i + 1 (for the first iteration,
      ),            //       this gives -0.1 + 1 = 0.9, rounded to 0)
      i,            //     set p = i
      q =           //     the flag q is set to 0 if this is the first
                    //     occurrence in a chain of valid matches:
        b[i - p] ?  //       if i - p is less than the length of b:
          t -= ~!q  //         add 2 to t if q = 0, or only 1 otherwise
                    //         either way, set q to a non-zero value
        :           //       else:
          0         //         set q to 0
    )               //   end of recursive call
  :                 // else:
    t               //   stop the recursion and return t
```

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>35 33 31</sup> 24 bytes

```
1#.1<1#.#@[>|@-//~@I.@E.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1DG2AhLJDtF2Ng66@fp2Dp56Dq95/Ta7U5Ix8BXVHR3WFNAV1D0cgABOO6lAZXV1ddS4I20DBVkG9pCg/B6wWxIBBdSQFuKVNQNI5BLT7@PvglcflUHOwJC5ZY5BsaipYNiQ1NSMVCJBdZWhkDEZgBTAOAiE7oKICrEj9PwA)

*-7 bytes after reading [Luis Mendo's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218985/15469) and realizing I could adapt it to J*

- `I.@E.` Indexes of matches
- `|@-//~@` Table of pairwise absolute differences
- `#@[>` Is it less than the substring length? (produces 0-1 table)
- `1#.` Sum rows
- `1<` Greater than 1?  (produces 0-1 list)
- `1#.` Sum

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
yXf&-|wn<s1>s
```

Inputs are in reverse order: `b`, then `a`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vzIiTU23pjzPptjQrvj/f/Wc/Bx1LvWSovwcGFQHAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L8yIk1Nt6Y8z6bY0K74v0vIf/WSovwcdS4wBYNALjaxHGyCPv4@mIKOQOzhCARgAsRzxBRKTQUSIampGampYKahkTEYITERCCiYmJQMJNUB).

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `'lol'` and `'trololololol'` as an example.

```
y     % Implicit inputs: b, a. Duplicate second-top element in stack
      % STACK: 'lol', 'trololololol', 'lol'
Xf    % Find second string in first string. Produces a row vector (possibly
      % empty) with the indices of all occurrences of b in a
      % STACK: 'lol', [4 6 8 10]
&-    % Square matrix of pairwise differences
      % STACK: 'lol', [0 2 4 6; -2 0 2 4; -4 -2 0 2; -6 -4 -2 0]
|     % Absolute value, element-wise
      % STACK: 'lol', [0 2 4 6; 2 0 2 4; 4 2 0 2; 6 4 2 0]
w     % Swap
      % STACK: [0 2 4 6; 2 0 2 4; 4 2 0 2; 6 4 2 0], 'lol'
n     % Number of elements
      % STACK: [0 2 4 6; 2 0 2 4; 4 2 0 2; 6 4 2 0], 3
<     % Less than? Element-wise
      % STACK: [1 1 0 0; 1 1 1 0; 0 1 1 1; 0 0 1 1]
s     % Sum of each column. For each ocurrence, this gives the number of
      % occurrences, including itself, that are close enough to overlap.
      % If there are no occurrences this gives 0
      % STACK: [2 3 3 2]
1>    % Greater than 1? Element-wise. For each occurrence, this gives 1 (true)
      % if there is a different occurrence that is close enough to overlap
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1]
s     % Sum. Implicit display
      % STACK: 4
```

(Note that the code `1>s` cannot be replaced by `qz` because when there are no occurrences of `b` in `a` that would give `1` instead of `0`, due to the behaviour of the previous `s`).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 102 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:sum(b==a[i-1:i+(T:=len(b)-1)]*(b in a[i+~T:i+T-1]or b in a[i:i+T*2])for
i in range(len(a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZK7boMwGEZ3P4UbFhuMEkKlVlQMbB0idfFGGezENEgEkCFDl7469QUiaEim1KDf8newDxg3392xrsLXRvbO05oX1boxCcjjz75kJ35gkBEetecT4nHM0sIPosJDNIpLUSGO/QBnLuKwqKCC3g9VlPpBVks4hjpxtxnOVVboTLLqSyA9n2GMe2fRM7NMHT71gmuJzdytSm@JwFQ0WdvdeDMtfbgsvcjI401ZGmTAOYgc5kjJcEQH15sU3VlW8J8/bra8NU8dNjGLjifmymbBfSXQgBHICdxrjABadbIux2tFoBmrfoPJAryDbPe8yHYfu8u890Q1UxKNkptA1xdDqBBHoZqOTQ1NHGzDP7d@YBwML4MjyNpWyM78WchxHO8JRHYThkjtBgb9Lw)

Explanation: it's pretty readable already. Just that `i+~T` == `i-T-1`, and the `:=` is equivalent to an assignment but can be inserted in a lambda (to make the code shorter)

Comment: Turns out `*` doesn't do what I expect, but it still works. (as long as `b` is not empty...)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
wÐƤẹ1ạ€`<L}S>1S
```

A dyadic Link accepting `a` on the left and `b` on the right which yields the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/88IRjSx7u2mn4cNfCR01rEmx8aoPtDIP///@vVFKUnwODSv@VQCQA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/88IRjSx7u2mn4cNfCR01rEmx8aoPtDIP/H16uD@T@/x8drVRSlJ8Dg0o6CmC@UiyXDqYMLvEcXBI@/j4QCQ9HIAATjiBxR@yiUOGQ1NSMVCAAiQFJsJihkTEaAsnCOBA1IJHyjMSS1LLUIqBILAA).

#### How?

```
wÐƤẹ1ạ€`<L}S>1S - Link: a, b
 ÐƤ             - for postfixes (of a):
w               -   first 1-indexed index (of b)
   ẹ1           - indices of 1 (i.e. X = a list of starts of b in a)
       `        - use (X) as both arguments of:
      €         -   for each (v in X):
     ạ          -     (v) absolute difference (across each of X)
                  -> list of lists of distances between starts
         L}     - length (of b)
        <       - less than
           S    - sum
            >1  - greater than 1 (i.e. not just overlapping itself)
              S - sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 43 bytes

```
(?=(.+)(.*¶)\1$)(.(?!\2))+?((?=\1)|(?<=\1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg81/D3lZDT1tTQ0/r0DbNGEMVIEvDXjHGSFNT214DKBljqFmjYW8DojX//y8pys@BQR0QhwtFBJ2fgy7g4@/D5eEIBGDCUccRlefIFZKampEKBDqpqVyGRsZoSAfG4irPSCxJLUstAgA) Takes input on separate lines but link includes test suite that splits on comma for convenience. Explanation: The program consists of a single match stage that outputs the count of matches of the pattern within the string `a`. For each match:

```
(?=(.+)(.*¶)\1$)
```

The remainder of the string `a` is split into two parts, the first of which must equal string `b` (which is therefore effectively captured into `$1`). The part of the string `a` after this match of the string `b` is captured into `$2`.

```
(.(?!\2))+?
```

Advance as few characters as possible, and definitely without reaching the end of this particular match of string `b` in string `a`.

```
((?=\1)|(?<=\1))
```

Find an overlapping match of string `b`. Note that in the case of a forward overlap, the lazy quantifier ensures that this match will always stop on or before the next match of string `b`.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>90</s> 89 bytes

```r
function(x,y,z=rle(diff(el(gregexpr(paste0("(?=",y,")"),x,,T)))<nchar(y)))sum(z$l[z$v]+1)
```

A byte saved by Dominic van Essen.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcqxDoJADADQ3a8wDUMvnonoCjFsDiQubMaBYA9ITiDHgcDPYwOyqLRN077WjGrr7UfVFInNywI72cvBN5rwkSuFpDE1lFJXGazi2tIBAc8@8BcIELKTMhJCeEWSxQZ7HuvmiYOjb4PT3neuGBWCNaVeEuS0gtj8HlZYr3h4DWe/BBxTC5iDv/jRiCgjDiZuE7nH01fxcZnnF4ZXFltqyYAY3w)

Comment: Nice!  You can still [save a byte](https://tio.run/##dcqxDoJADADQ3a8wDUMvnonoCjFsDiQubMaBYA9ITiDHgcDPYwOyqLRN077WjGrr7UfVFInNywI72cvBN5rwkSuFpDE1lFJXGazi2tIBAc8@8BcIELKTMhJCeEWSxQZ7HuvmiYOjb4PT3neuGBWCNaVeEuS0gtj8HlZYr3h4DWe/BBxTC5iDv/jRiCgjDiZuE7nH01fxcZnnF4ZXFltqyYAY3w) using ```el```...

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 117 bytes

```perl
sub f{($a,$b,$f,%s,$c)=@_;!$s{$x=1+index$a,$b,$_}++&&$x&&($w=$f&&$x-$f<length$b,$f=$x,$c+=$j*$w,$j=2-$w)for 0..99;$c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJbT4NAEIXf/RXTzUgKbJteNKbWjfbNxEZe@qaGQF16sdIKKDQNvx2X5VK2ibEDWThnvzkZwu54sLnOsvDbBe/QRoeiS9GjlyHFuc4e7HELwwMmrG@u/HeelICdmqamYaJpbYwZevl7B727DfcX0VJGMExEhMlwbWBMcc0GHYx1bxtAr9sdjcY4TzOh2i8kCrab6iIUqpL@Uffe6EX@/JtX1Bm8Kq/@5afWtCGP@Y8TUXKZNAcgijqHV@RNzc84X3JRSpzgVWdY8/3B8OSWXO0XXcfvPcmt8@OlE/EfHhT7@fz6QbZ87quDwpOdOCRoj0sfcLGNWM/0CkAv/F2w8iO5BfwL8ia4F7/rg8AtEMMwnq0ZWE8t0qRJOYWAmeyAPFlmgMPQAXAZuq@@aEqzXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
Ｉ↨Ｅ⌕Ａθη⊙↔⁻⌕Ａθηι∧λ‹λＬη¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwymxOFXDN7FAwy0zL8UxJ0ejUEchQ1NHwTGvUsMxqTg/p7QEKJ@ZV1qMriJTE6wsRSNHR8EntbgYQuell2RoZGiCgI6CIZC0/v/f0MgYDXHBWP91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Conveniently, Charcoal's `FindAll` command also includes overlapping matches.

```
     θ                  First input
      η                 Second input
   ⌕Ａ                   Find all matches
  Ｅ                     Map over positions
          ⌕Ａθη          All matches
        ↔⁻              Absolute difference with
              ι         Current match
       ⊙                Does any difference satisfy
                λ       Current difference
               ∧        Non-zero and
                  λ     Current difference
                 ‹      Less than
                   Ｌ    Length of
                    η   Second string
 ↨                   ¹  Take the sum
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

I don't use `Sum` here because it doesn't output `0` for an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.sIÅ?ƶ0KDδαIg‹O1›O
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218990/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fr9jzcKv9sW0G3i7ntpzb6Jn@qGGnv@Gjhl3@//@XFOXnwCAXEAMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6H@94ojDrfbHthl4u5zbcm5jRPqjhp3@ho8advn/1/kfHa1UUpSfA4NKOmCuUqwOhjh20Rzswj7@PmBhD0cgABOOQFFHbGIQwZDU1IxUIACKAAmQiKGRMRoCysHYYBVAfnlGYklqWWqRUmwsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.s                  # Get all suffices of the (implicit) input-string
  IÅ?               # Check for each if they start with the second input-string
                    # (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
     ƶ              # Multiply each value by their 1-based index
      0K            # Remove all 0s
         δ          # Apply double-vectorized,
        D           # with a copy of itself:
          α         #  Get the absolute different between the values
           Ig‹      # Check for each that it's lower than the length of the second input
              O     # Sum the checks of each row together
               1›   # Check for each whether it's larger than 1
                 O  # And sum those checks together again
                    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 20 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
+/1<1⊥≢⍤⊣>∘|∘.-⍨⍤⍸⍤⍷
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=09Y3tDF81LX0UeeiR71LHnUttnvUMaMGiPV0H/WuAAn17gCT2wE&f=U8/Jz1FXSFNQLynKz4FBdS4wF1McAA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

A train submission which takes `b` on the left, and `a` on the right.

-2 bytes from Adám(helped trainify the function)

### Explanation

```
                   ⍷ boolean array where b occurs in a
                 ⍸⍤  indices of 1s in it
            ∘.-⍨⍤    all pairwise differences
           |         take the absolute value of it(vectorized)
      ≢⍤⊣            length of b        
         >           greater than the absolute values?(vectorizes)
    1⊥               sum the columns of that result
  1<                 are they >1?                                  
+/                   sum the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-00p`), 54 bytes

```perl
$_=/
(.+)(.*\1)$/?()=/(?=$1$2$2)|(?<=$1)$2$2(?!$2)/g:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xCsIwEIb3ewqFDDnFXltxUUvo5lBwcSyIw2ELsQ1pUASf3ZgKCm3/@znu@7YzbPXGd1RKvhn3nHXO1s21RKKdF@eMQEZLlNGiTFCQkpiRVJlIRCpSfEm1Dzf2INU8GLpuY@@dbfVvoAeAgZoIPTHFsQA45CHflUM@wsAn5opDIBSSdD3qXwEMfkN4VBfHd7bv1ri6bTq/imNtPg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8FYK5M8tWDxWbAro&input=InRyb2xvbG9sb2xvbCIKImxvbCI=), 12 bytes

Been quite a while since I've done any Japt, probably has some room for improvement.

```sh
ðV
äÏ-X<Vl
è
```

[Try it out here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8FYK5M8tWDxWbAro&input=InRyb2xvbG9sb2xvbCIKImxvbCI=)

Explanation:

```sh
ðV      # Get all indices of needle in input
äÏ-X<Vl # For every consecutive pair in the result, check if their distance is small enough that they overlap
è       # Return the number of items that were true
```